# Type is not narrowed from function using type guards

Tags: typescript, types, narrowing, typeguards

I have a function that takes parameters of similar structure and inside the function uses type guards to figure out the type of parameter passed in.

```
type Ex1 = {
  contents: 'contents',
  param1: 'yes'
}

type Ex2 = {
  contents: 'contents',
  param2: true
}

type Ex = Ex1 | Ex2;

export const exampleFunc = (example: Ex): Ex => {
  const isEx1 = (unknownExample: Ex): unknownExample is Ex1 => {
    return (unknownExample as Ex1).param1 === undefined ? false : true;
  }

  const execute = (): Ex => {
    if (isEx1(example)) {
      return example;
    }

    return example;
  }

  return execute()
}
```

In my actual application, a complex object of a different type is returned, but in this example, i simply return the same object.

When I execute the function

```
const ex1: Ex1 = {
  contents: 'contents',
  param1: 'yes'
}
const test = exampleFunc(ex1);
```

In my IDE, I can see that TS correctly understands that `example` in the following block

```
if (isEx1(example)) {
  return example;
}
```

is of the correct type

> (parameter) example: Ex1

You can see that the object assigned to `example` is returned from the function and in this case assigned to `test`.

However, despite understanding the correct type in the return blocks, Typscript doesn't then assign `test` as type `Ex1` and instead assigns it as the more broad type `Ex`.

```
const test = exampleFunc(ex1);
```

which means that the following throws an error

```
test.param1
```

> Property 'param1' does not exist on type 'Ex'.

Are type guards only useful in the current execution block or am I misunderstanding their use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Narrowing only applies to the local scope in which it occurs. Since your `exampleFunc` declares that it returns an `Ex`, the type system will treat it as an `Ex` regardless of what happens inside the function.

Comment: This is especially true given that you are exporting the function; one can imagine the type guard being extended through the return of functions that aren't visible outside the module in a future version of TypeScript, but this is a non-starter when part of the public interface.